# Are there any SMTP servers I can install on linux / mac?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email

Are there any SMTP servers I can install on my linux (ubuntu) or mac OS X?

I have [msmtp](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Msmtp) as a client and I want to have a server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are *many* different SMTP server implementations you can install on GNU/Linux or Mac OS X. Hundreds.

See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mail_servers) on them.

Comment: and compare them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers

Comment: all I need to do is install one of them and that it?

Comment: @0x90 Yes, why would you need multiple servers?